# Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'release()'! when uograded to 0.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Not able to solve this error, I have updated Android studio. gone throungh other [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257106/build-script-error-unsupported-gradle-dsl-method-found-release) solutions but not worked for me, please help..

Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'release()'!
        Possible causes could be:
        - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent 
        - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method
        - or there is a mistake in a build script
        Gradle settings

Gradle version - 0.9

Main gradle.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }

}
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19

    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

}
```

Project Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '18.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('dsc.jks')
            storePassword 'dscneo'
            keyAlias 'dsc'
            keyPassword 'dscneo'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
        }
        beta {
            versionNameSuffix '-BETA'
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.1.jar')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':TabIndicatorLibrary')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile project(':VerticalViewPager')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/HockeySDK-3.0.1.jar')
}
```

Facebook SDK gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Other library project gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '18.0.1'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

one more library project gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Comment: post your gradle files and your gradle-wrapper version.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti edited, please check..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your last file (library) you have the `release` block inside the `android` block.

*The DSL for the library projects is now the same as for the application projects*

In particolar you have to put the *release* block inside the *buildTypes*.

```
android {
    buildTypes {           
        release {
        }
    }
```

Also I suggest you use  `buildToolsVersion '19.0.x'` for all your gradle files.

You can put it in your build.gradle in root folder.

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 19
    buildToolsVersion = "19.0.3"
}
```

Then in each build.gradle file you can use:

```
 compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
 buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
```

Comment: thnx Gabriele, will try this :)

Comment: Not working Sir m getting this  :( Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':checkDebugManifest'.
> File '/home/webwerks/AndroidStudioProjects/dsc/DubaiSportsCouncilProject/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'manifest' does not exist.

Comment: is it located in DubaiSportsCouncilProject/src/main/And‌​roidManifest.xm? Your message error says File .. does not exist.

Comment: @msn Your directory structure should be: app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: +1 ...I come from a different question, but this answer helped me with some other issue.